# Angular Bootstrap ng-select alignment

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, angular-ngselect

I'm trying to use ng-select in an angular project with ng-bootstrap. I find that the input text box to search the select list is not aligned properly.
Here's the html code:

```
<div class="container">
  <form [formGroup]="sampleForm" >
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
        <span><b>Country</b></span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
        <span><b>City</b></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
        <select id="country" formControlName="country" class="form-control">
          <option *ngFor="let c of countries;" [ngValue]="c">{{c}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
        <ng-select #citySelect [items]="cities"
                   id="city"
                   [selectOnTab]="true"
                   [bindValue]="cities"
                   class="form-control"
                   formControlName="city">
        </ng-select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here's the typescript:

```
  countries: string[] = ['USA', 'India'];
  cities: string[] = ['Mumbai', 'Mangalore', 'Pune', 'Pokhran', 'Chennai', 'Bengaluru'];
  sampleForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private config: NgSelectConfig) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sampleForm = this.fb.group({
      country: ['', []],
      city: ['', []]
    });
    this.config.appendTo = 'body';
  }
```

If you run the code, you'll see that the input box for city is shifted out. Any ideas on how to fix this would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance
AR

********* Edit
Here's a link to a stackblitz repo:
https://angular-ivy-wiqfdy.stackblitz.io
It seems to work fine there. However, on my machine, it's still out of alignment.

Here's a snapshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please edit your question to include a Minimal, Reproducible Example of the problem (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  You also can check how to do it here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers

Comment: @Skatt... thanks... added a stackblitz link

Comment: Apologies... here's the url to the development site: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wiqfdy?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `class=form-control`

```
  <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
    <ng-select #citySelect [items]="cities"
               id="city"
               [selectOnTab]="true"
               [bindValue]="cities"
               formControlName="city">
    </ng-select>
  </div>
```

Comment: brilliant... thank you. Any idea why the addition of that class caused this issue?

Comment: Because it adds extra padding as it is ment to be used with native inputs.